# How can i convert the request to MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, mongotemplate

I made a request using mongoDB Compass and it works, but I can't transfer it to my java program. I think I've tried all the options. Perhaps there is a way to use this pipeline directly in the code, but I did not find it

```
[{
    $match: {
        $or: [{
                riskReport: {
                    $ne: null
                }
            },
            {
                riskOfDealReport: {
                    $ne: null
                }
            },
            {
                controlProcedureReport: {
                    $ne: null
                }
            },
            {
                matrixReport: {
                    $ne: null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        controlProcedureReport: '$controlProcedureReport',
        riskReport: '$riskReport',
        matrixReport: '$matrixReport',
        documentName: {
            $concatArrays: [
                '$riskReport.ids.value',
                '$controlProcedureReport.ids.value',
                '$matrixReport.ids'
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$documentName'
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        year: '$_id.year',
        periodCode: '$_id.periodCode',
        serialNumber: '$_id.serialNumber',
        formationDate: '$formationDate',
        status: '$status',
        documentName: '$documentName',
        fileId: {
            $cond: {
                'if': {
                    $in: [
                        '$documentName',
                        '$controlProcedureReport.ids.value'
                    ]
                },
                then: '$controlProcedureReport.fileId',
                'else': {
                    $cond: {
                        'if': {
                            $in: [
                                '$documentName',
                                '$riskReport.ids.value'
                            ]
                        },
                        then: '$riskReport.fileId',
                        'else': {
                            $cond: {
                                'if': {
                                    $in: [
                                        '$documentName',
                                        '$matrixReport.ids'
                                    ]
                                },
                                then: '$matrixReport.fileId',
                                'else': ''
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

I tried to use this code but I get an error

```
        ProjectionOperation project2 = Aggregation.project()
                .and("_id.year").as("year")
                .and("_id.periodCode").as("periodCode")
                .and("_id.serialNumber").as("serialNumber")
                .and("formationDate").as("formationDate")
                .and("status").as("status")
                .and("documentName").as("documentName")
                .and(ConditionalOperators.when(
                                     ArrayOperators.arrayOf("controlProcedureReport.ids.value").containsValue("$documentName")
                             ).thenValueOf("controlProcedureReport.fileId")
                             .otherwise(
                                     ConditionalOperators.when(
                                                     ArrayOperators.arrayOf("riskReport.ids.value").containsValue("$documentName")
                                             ).thenValueOf("riskReport.fileId")
                                             .otherwise("")
                             )
                ).as("fileId");

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(packageCriteria),
                project1,
                unwind,
                project2,
                procedureResults,
                icsDisclosures,
                icsDisclosureRegulations
        );

        List<Document> mappedResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, DOCUMENT_PACKAGE_COLLECTION, Document.class).getMappedResults();
```

With this code I am getting an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gweni.png)

Healp me please

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Comment: It seems `_id.year` does not exists. Can you check which object is returned just before last project stage?. Also you can provide some data example to try out.